# Pattern to share ajax and non-ajax action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website that uses many ajax requests to show data. One of which is a messages view.

The user gets notified by email when he gets a new message, the link I provide is something like this: /mailmessages/show/67?layout=true

The layout=true parameter decides if a layout is rendered or not. With an ajax call it's false.

Is this the way to do it? Or is there a better solution for this. Putting the parameter everywhere doesn't feel like a good solution.

Edit: I'm using plain jquery ajax calls, not any microsoft solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check :

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest
```

And render differently based on that.

**EDIT**

Then you could check Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] - it should be XMLHttpRequest if it's ajax.

To be sure do a debug and see what header jQuery sets, and also check if just using IsAjaxRequest works :) (the same header as ms ajax will probably be set).

Comment: Forgot to mention: I'm using jquery to do the ajax calls. Not microsoft.ajax.